# Is the proof to a recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{5}a_n^2$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, solution-verification

We have a recursive sequence:
$$a_1 = 1$$
$$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{5}a_n^2$$
We need to show that the sequence is convergent. We also need to analyse what would happen if we would pick a different first term $a_n$

What I did:

$$
a_{n+1} \geq a_n\\
1+\frac{1}{5}a_n^2 \geq a_n\\
a_n^2-5a_n+5\geq 0\\
(a_n-\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2})(a_n -\frac{5+\sqrt5}{2})\geq 0\\
\implies$$
$\text{so this implies that if all the terms are bellow}$ $\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$ or above $\frac{5+\sqrt5}{2}$ then the sequence is increasing

We see that $a_1 = 1$ is bellow $\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$, so let's prove that $a_n \leq \frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$ by induction:

$n = 1:$
$$a_1 = 1 \leq \frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$$
$$\text{holds}$$
$n \rightarrow n+1:$
$$
\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2} \geq a_{n+1} \\
\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2} \geq 1+\frac{1}{5}a_n^2\\
\frac{15-5\sqrt5}{2} \geq a_n^2\\
\text{for this to hold $a_n$ should not be between the positive and the negative root.}\\
\text{But we see that $\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$ is more than the $-\sqrt{\frac{15-5\sqrt5}{2}}$ sp this means that the sequence isn't increasing.}
$$

I do not know how to prove this, or if my process is correct and I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Note that $$
a_n  \le \frac{{5 - \sqrt 5 }}{5} \Rightarrow a_{n + 1}  = 1 + \frac{1}{5}a_n^2  \le 1 + \frac{1}{5}\left( {\frac{{5 - \sqrt 5 }}{5}} \right)^2  = \frac{{5 - \sqrt 5 }}{5}.
$$

Comment: @Gary I see, thanks. But is the procedure before the proving $a_n \leq \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{5}$ correct ?

Comment: It is not correct. For $a_n^2\le\frac{15-5\sqrt5}2$ to hold $a_n$ should belong between the positive and negative root

Comment: @ShubhamJohri So I could continue this kind of proof and show that the sequence is only between this two roots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1=1<\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

suppose now that $a_k\le \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$$a_{k+1}=1+\frac15 a_k^2\le 1+\frac15 \cdot\left( \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

therefore $a_n\le \frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for any $n$.

**Edit**
As it is monotone increasing and bounded the sequence converges to $a$.

To find $a$ we use the definition of the sequence
$$a=\frac{1}{5}a^2+1$$
which gives $a=\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: I also have a more general question regarding recursive sequences. We have proven that the sequence is increasing, and that one of the upper bounds is $\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, what argument shows that this is also the least upper bound or in other words the supremum of the sequence ?

Comment: The sequence is increasing and is bounded, so it is convergent. Let $A$ be the limit. Then $A$ must satisfy $A=1+A^2 /5$. The smaller positive root is $(5-\sqrt{5})/5$ which is also an upper bound to the sequence, so it must be the correct limit and the supremum as well.

Comment: @BiliDebili I have edited the answer. Hope it is clear

Comment: @Raffaele Can I also ask, if the proof in my question that the sequence is increasing $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ is correct ?

Comment: @BiliDebili I tried to review your work here https://imgur.com/QEi8RKj

Comment: I have another question, to find the candidates for the limit points, I would have to assume that the limit exists before showing that the sequence is bounded above, so that I do not have to do double calculation. In my case I already showed what the limit is by stating that the sequence only increases on that interval where in the first paragraph the first solution was. Thus, if it is increasing only on that paragraph, is it neccessary to calculate again the limit point out of the equation.


Long question short: Do we have to solve the limit equation at the end again, if we already solved

Comment: .... it to show that the sequence is increasing